# Wrong path for js vendor/assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

application.js requires jquery-ui file from vendor/assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js. But result is like that:

```
<script src="/javascripts/../jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

All other js plugins works well, asset pipeline finds them. But can't find properly **jquery-ui**, **jquery-block-ui** and **jquery-slimscroll**

And how a regular script tag look like:

```
<script src="/assets/pace.min-6a1cbb46da15c9d3662ad8b47fd43ee9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

Why Asset Pipeline can't find the right path for these plugins?

Application.js file is like that:

```
//= require jquery-2.1.4.min
//= require jquery-ui.min
//= require pace.min.js
//= require jquery.blockui
//= require js/bootstrap.min
//= require jquery.slimscroll.min
//= require switchery.min
//= require jquery.uniform.min
//= require js/classie.js
//= require js/main.js
//= require jquery.waypoints.min
//= require toastr.min
//= require jquery.flot.min
//= require jquery.flot.time.min
//= require jquery.flot.symbol.min
//= require jquery.flot.resize.min
//= require jquery.flot.tooltip.min
//= require curvedLines
//= require MetroJs.min
//= require modern

//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Can you post your your application.js file and did you include the gem which is handling query-ui ?

Comment: Hi, @Typpex I updated question with application.js file. All my requirements come from vendor/assets file. Everything works fine in application.js file but jquery-ui, jquery.slimscroll.min and jquery.blockui are not.

Comment: Could you try downloading them from here: https://rails-assets.org/ and use then as instructed on the page?

Comment: What is the error in the javascript console ? Do you use the gem handling query and query-ui assets ?

Comment: @Typpex Console output says: "/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js", "/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockui.js" and "/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" are not found. Because script tags for these are like : "<script src="/javascripts/../jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>" but they should be like "<script src="/assets/pace.min-6a1cbb46da15c9d3662ad8b47fd43ee9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>"

Answer (score 0):

The asset pipeline can not find your JS file because they simply don't exist i suppose. For this to work you would need a query-2.1.4.min.js file in your javascript folder for instance. I can see you don't have any issue with jquery_ujs so i suppose you are using the gem jquery-rails.

You should replace //= require jquery-2.1.4.min with //= require jquery2 as described in the following link: https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails#installation. On their page it is stated that jquery-ui is no longer included in the jquery-rails gem so you need to use gem "query-ui-rails" in your Gemfile to be able to include query-ui in application.js